# How to Install new_relic into django application running under apache and mod_wsgi

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi, newrelic

I am running Django using apache and mod_wsgi and i wanted to install new_relic

I already preconfiure the newrelic.ini and put it in django base dir

in new_relic doc they say to prefix with following :

```
NEW_RELIC_CONFIG_FILE=newrelic.ini newrelic-admin run-program
```

but the file /var/www//index.wsgi looks like:

```
import os
import sys
import site
#...
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

how i emerge the new_relic into the django application using mod-wsgi ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply googling for "new relic mod_wsgi" sent me to New Relic's own page entitled [Python agent and mod_wsgi](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/python-agent/hosting-mechanisms/python-agent-and-modwsgi), which clearly explains what to do:

> The New Relic Python agent can be used with Apache/mod_wsgi... For integration of the Python agent into your application when using Apache/mod_wsgi you should follow the standard instructions for manual integration with your Python application. The wrapper script cannot be used with Apache/mod_wsgi.

Following the link to the "manual integration" takes you to [this page](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/python-agent/installation-configuration/python-agent-integration#manual-integration), which has exact instructions for what to add to your wsgi file.

Comment: Thanks! , I have to say that it queit surprise that there is no newrelic-standard solution for the django /mod_wsgi .